# hibernate annotation config in tomee : Missing required persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, spring-java-config, apache-tomee

I'm trying to run Spring mvc annotation config with Tomee.
I dont have any xml config in my project, but i have got

> Missing required persistence.xml

this is my config file

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"controller","service","model"})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver configureViewResolvers() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver ;
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"model"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/e");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private final Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();                 
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

and stack trace

```
31-May-2017 16:52:39.386 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.logResults FAIL ... EE-System-0.8.0:   Missing required persistence.xml for @PersistenceContext ref "java:comp/env/aa" to unit ""
31-May-2017 16:52:39.387 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.logResults Invalid EjbModule(name=EE-System-0.8.0, path=D:\ee-system\ear\target\ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT\EE-System-0.8.0)
31-May-2017 16:52:39.388 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.logResults FAIL ... ee:    Missing required persistence.xml for @PersistenceContext ref "java:comp/env/aa" to unit ""
31-May-2017 16:52:39.390 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.logResults Invalid WebModule(name=EE-System-0.8.0, path=D:\ee-system\ear\target\ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT\EE-System-0.8.0)
31-May-2017 16:52:39.391 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.deploy Set the 'openejb.validation.output.level' system property to VERBOSE for increased validation details.
31-May-2017 16:52:39.881 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy Can't deploy D:\ee-system\ear\target\ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear
 org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.deploy(ReportValidationResults.java:88)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build(AppInfoBuilder.java:321)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1040)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:244)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer._invoke(SingletonContainer.java:256)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:212)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:371)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:360)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:247)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

any idea and help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if your application doesn't use EE maybe just add in conf/exclusions.list the prefix of your jars (like myapp-) to exclude it and avoid the container to scan your spring code and analyzis it in a EE fashion.